# Sonata Admin - Injecting securityContext into Admin class

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I need to write the name of logged user in some fields of my model (I've got a parent document and some embedded documents)

I've injected security context in my admin class

```
calls:
    - [ setTranslationDomain, [QMAdminBundle]]
    - [ setSecurityContext, [@security.context]]
```

then I wrote my setSecurityContext

```
public function setSecurityContext($securityContext) {
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
}

public function getSecurityContext() {
    return $this->securityContext;
}

public function prePersist($appunto) {
    $user = $this->getSecurityContext()->getToken()->getUser();
    $appunto->setOperatore($user->getUsername());
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't write the user... maybe this happens because I've got a parent document (where I don't need to write the user) and some embedded documents (where I want to write the user) that I show in the parent form (please see image)?

I use fosuserbundle, and a bundle that (easy-)extends sonata user: I have to use them to get the user?

Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot

[image: form with embedded documents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
$appunto->setOperatore($user->getUsername());
```

in the `prePersist` function, it'll save it once you've pressed the save button, right before it's persisted in memory.

Try to set the operator on the appunto object in the `__constructor()` function, and it'll show the username in the `appunto` object.

Remember that you'll have to set the user for each subobjects 
like `$appunto->getSubObject()->setOperatore($user);`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't understood your hint: you suggest me to set operator in _contructor() in my Operator document? thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, in your SonataAdmin class constructor.You can do it directly in your object constructor if you want to set it in a global way each time you instanciate a new object

Comment: ok, I've tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe I'm missing something.